# preg_match() for image how do I do it?

Tags: php

I am searching code to validate a user-submitted URL to ensure it ends with `.jpg`, `.png` or `.jpeg`, but I can't find it.

I want it to be done with `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with preg_match like this:

```
if(preg_match('/\.(jpg|png|jpeg)$/', $url)) {

}
```

But there is an other way too using [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$extension = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (in_array($extension, array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'))) {

}
```

If you want a more strict validation, then parse the URL first and get the extension from the `path` part:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$extension = pathinfo($parts['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (in_array($extension, array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'))) {

}
```

Comment: pathinfo() is also fine, but I can't get it to work.

If I use tha preg_match() one you can submit this image.exe?extension=.jpg and I don't want that.

Comment: @user3368850 Extended my answer with a more strict validation which doesn't allow `image.exe?extension=.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your URL is in the variable `$url` this should work:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';

$an_image = preg_match("/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i", $url);

if ($an_image) {
  echo 'This is an image!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$post_content = '<a href="http://www.test.com" title="test">test.com</a> there is  https://img.srgcdn.com/e//aUVTYlRFNXgyeFBQUGZNUk1DSzMuanBn.jpg  another example <a href="http://www.test1.com">test1.com</a> one more here too <a href="http://www.test2.com" title="test2">test2.com</a>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?vi=hjsdGD08xfg9c  ';
preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/i', $post_content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: When answering a five year old question with existing answers is is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. In addition code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. Snippets should be used for code that can execute in context, for languages like php just format the code as code rather than using a snippet.

Comment: i'm sorry but the solution works. Its a complete solution to getting image urls.